# Bug Process finished with exit code 138 (interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS)

Tags: sigbus

I ask for your help because I have a problem :(

I am currently in a computer project with a group. We have to code a Dofus 
My team codes under Windows and I under Mac OS.
We all use the Allegro5 graphics library.
We are on JetBrain's CLion IDE and we code in C.

In our project, compiling under Windows poses no problem. On the other hand, under MacOS the error message:
Process finished with exit code 138 (interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS)
is posted.

Our teacher couldn't identify the error so I'm calling on you.

Thank you very much for any answers given!

Answer (score 0):

From the support ([here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007718779-Process-finished-with-exit-code-138-139-interrupted-by-signal-10-SIGBUS-SIGSEGV-)), it seems this is a randomly occurring issue on the platform. Have you tried many times?

Comment: Yes.
The problem here is that my teammates don't have this problem.